# How to prevent a longclick while scrolling a TextView in Android?

Tags: android, scroll, onlongclicklistener

In an Android app I have a `TextView` that can be scrolled, clicked and longclicked. My problem is that when I scroll the `TextView` it also thinks it's being longclicked.

I tried something like:

```
TV.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    scrolled = false;
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            System.out.println("SCROLLED!!");
            scrolled = true;
        return true;
       }
    }
 });
```

But I can see it's being scrolled when longclicked and not moved (maybe too sensitive?). I tried with `MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL`, the logical option, but it doesn't even react (????).

I really have no idea what else to try.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you handle your own longclick detection like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093232/android-long-press-with-scroll/12156244#12156244)
Then you would just cancel the longpress callback as soon as you detect a `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`.

In case you use the `OnLongClickListener` you can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272409/stop-onlongclicklistener-from-firing-while-dragging)